# Dynamic website title glitching with data from SSR

Tags: next.js

I'm using NextJS and whenever the user access the page, I'm doing a SSR request to the backend to get the website information and retrieve it.

Then, with the data of the website, I'm doing:

```
<Head>
   <title>{props.template.websiteName} | Home</title>
</Head>
```

What is happening is, let's say the title is `Awesome`. Whenever I refresh the page for example, the title becomes `Awesome <!-- --> | Home`. I don't understand why it's giving me this `<!-- -->` on the title when I refresh for example. When the website fully loads, then the title becomes correct: `Awesome | Home`.

Note: Since it is doing a SSR request, the page should only "display" when I already have the data, right? So it should not glitch. Also, there is nothing wrong with the request or anything, the website works fine, the data coming is fine, it's just glitching the title when the website is "refreshing" or in "loading state".

What can I do to avoid this? I don't even know why it is happening.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem, use this instead:

```
<Head>
  <title>{String(props.template.websiteName + ' | Home')}</title>
</Head>
```

Probably on your console it is saying that the title element received an array with more than 1 element. Using this way you can make sure it is only one string.